# How to upload and download mysql database in a remote Digital Ocean server?

Tags: mysql, sql, import, export

I want to know the way to upload and download the .sql file that is required for importing and exporting a **mysql database in a remote server**.

I followed the tutorial on digital ocean for importing/exporting a database:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-download-the-files-and-folders-in-my-droplet-from-the-console

But after exporting the database it is stored as a file on the server. **How do I download that .sql file in my local computer?**

**Similarly, If I have a .sql file on my local machine how do I store it in server and then run the import sql script to populate the database?**

Comment: use SFTP clients like Filezilla to connect to your droplet and then download the file to ur local machine

Comment: Yeah I considered that option but I thought if there would be something that directly downloads the output of mysqldump to local machine

Comment: you can use mysqldump `-h` flag to specify the host to connect to (using terminal in your own machine). But I would recommend against it.